# Adding script after jQuery

Tags: javascript

I would like to add my script after jQuery. This is what I have tried:

```html
<body>
  I should be hidden!
  <script>
  let code = `$('body').hide();`;

  const dynamicScript = () => {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.defer = true;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
    script.classList.add('my-script');
    script.innerHTML = code;  
  }

  document.onload = dynamicScript();
  </script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</body>
```

Even though I use appendChind(), it still adds my script before jQuery. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I assume you are using some kind of web processor which is building your page and puts your code before jquery. if this is the case put jquery import line in master/base page on top before main secction

Comment: @Nicolae it is true that I am using a tool but I have no permission to change the position of the jQuery script tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution with setTimeout(). Not the best solution but that one puts the script behind jQuery after 100ms:

```html
<body>
  I should be hidden!
  <script>
    let code = `$('body').hide();`;

    const dynamicScript = () => {
      const script = document.createElement('script');
      script.defer = true;
      script.classList.add('my-script');
      script.innerHTML = code;
      window.setTimeout(() => {
       document.body.appendChild(script); 
      }, 100);
      
    }

    document.onload = dynamicScript();

  </script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</body>
```